# How to improve join performance using LIKE and Wildcards?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a series of joins that merges a contacts table with a deals table using the operators LIKE, CASE and wildcards. The query is really slow with an execution: 1 m 4 s 244 ms and fetching: 677 ms. How would I improve the performance of this query?

```
from contacts left join deals on deals.associated_vids like
                          Case
                              when canonical_vid = split_part(associated_vids, ',', 1)
                                  then concat(canonical_vid,'%')
                              when canonical_vid =
                                   split_part(associated_vids, ',', (CHAR_LENGTH(associated_vids) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(associated_vids, ',', ''))) / CHAR_LENGTH(',')+1)
                                  then concat('%',canonical_vid)
                              when canonical_vid is not null
                                  then concat('%,', concat(canonical_vid,',%')) End
```

I would like to get the full run time down as much as possible preferably less than a minute.

Comment: Redshift or Postgres? Although they share some common roots, they are substantially different.

Comment: We are using redshift so the semantics will be from there.

Comment: I highly doubt you could optimize a "like" query, it still requires a full table scan

Comment: Is there a way to break up how the like function so you get the same result but by using a different function? For example, using several unions over one like clause?

Comment: can you provide an example of values that you'd like to match?

Comment: associated_vids = 1043551,6876201,6876251,735651,3856754,6876001,6072551,6876051,6876101,6876151 canonical_vid = 6876251